# Neural network back propagation regression, how to correctly learn the cos function?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

After `Lutz Lehmann`'s suggestion, I discovered that it was a problem of random weights and biases. I used np.ramdom.seed(2021) to specify the random seed number, and the error has not converged. But if I use np.ramdom.seed(10) as the random seed number,the 600th ephoch error will converge to a relatively small amount.

`Galletti_Lance`'s suggestion is correct and should be replaced with a periodic activation function. I expanded the interval of the `sin` function, and the learning error did not converge.Sure enough, it is overfitting.

```
input_data = np.arange(0, np.pi * 4, 0.1)  # input
correct_data = np.sin(input_data)  # correct answer
input_data = (input_data - np.pi*2) / np.pi
```

`np.random.seed(2021)` Learning cos function, the 20000th epoch is as follows:

```
Epoch:0/20001 Error:0.2904405534384431
Epoch:200/20001 Error:0.2752981376571506
Epoch:400/20001 Error:0.27356300803051226
Epoch:600/20001 Error:0.27409878767315193
Epoch:800/20001 Error:0.2638216736165815
Epoch:1000/20001 Error:0.27196157366033213
Epoch:1200/20001 Error:0.2743520487664953
Epoch:1400/20001 Error:0.2589745966244678
Epoch:1600/20001 Error:0.2705289192984957
Epoch:1800/20001 Error:0.2689693217636388
....
Epoch:20000/20001 Error:0.2678723095120438
```

[image: The 2000th epoch is as follows:]
But if I use np.ramdom.seed(10) as the random seed number,the 600th ephoch error will converge to a relatively small amount.

```
Epoch:0/20001 Error:0.283958515549615
Epoch:200/20001 Error:0.260819823215878
Epoch:400/20001 Error:0.23267630899157743
Epoch:600/20001 Error:0.0022589485429890047
Epoch:800/20001 Error:0.0007425256677052262
Epoch:1000/20001 Error:0.0003946220094805989
....
Epoch:2800/20001 Error:0.00011495288247859594
Epoch:3000/20001 Error:9.989662843897715e-05
....
Epoch:20000/20001 Error:4.6146397913360866e-05
```

`np.random.seed(10)`  Learning cos function, the 600th epoch is as follows:

[image: The 600th epochare is as follows:]

---

---

I use neural network back propagation regression to learn the cos function. When I learn the sin function, it is normal. If it is changed to cos, it is abnormal. What is the problem?

`correct_data = np.cos(input_data)`

Related settings:

1.The activation function of the middle layer: sigmoid function

2.Excitation function of the output layer: identity function

3.Loss function: sum of squares error

4.Optimization algorithm: stochastic gradient descent method

5.Batch size: 1

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# - Prepare to input and correct answer data -
input_data = np.arange(0, np.pi * 2, 0.1)  # input
correct_data = np.cos(input_data)  # correct answer
input_data = (input_data - np.pi) / np.pi  # Converge the input to the range of -1.0-1.0
n_data = len(correct_data)  # number of data

# - Each setting value -
n_in = 1  # The number of neurons in the input layer
n_mid = 3  # The number of neurons in the middle layer
n_out = 1  # The number of neurons in the output layer

wb_width = 0.01  # The spread of weights and biases
eta = 0.1  # learning coefficient
epoch = 2001
interval = 200  # Display progress interval practice


# -- middle layer --
class MiddleLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_upper, n):  # Initialize settings
        self.w = wb_width * np.random.randn(n_upper, n)  # weight (matrix)
        self.b = wb_width * np.random.randn(n)  # offset (vector)

    def forward(self, x):  # forward propagation
        self.x = x
        u = np.dot(x, self.w) + self.b
        self.y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-u))  # Sigmoid function

    def backward(self, grad_y):  # Backpropagation
        delta = grad_y * (1 - self.y) * self.y  # Differentiation of Sigmoid function

        self.grad_w = np.dot(self.x.T, delta)
        self.grad_b = np.sum(delta, axis=0)

        self.grad_x = np.dot(delta, self.w.T)

    def update(self, eta):  # update of weight and bias
        self.w -= eta * self.grad_w
        self.b -= eta * self.grad_b


# - Output layer -
class OutputLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_upper, n):  # Initialize settings
        self.w = wb_width * np.random.randn(n_upper, n)  # weight (matrix)
        self.b = wb_width * np.random.randn(n)  # offset (vector)

    def forward(self, x):  # forward propagation
        self.x = x
        u = np.dot(x, self.w) + self.b
        self.y = u  # Identity function

    def backward(self, t):  # Backpropagation
        delta = self.y - t

        self.grad_w = np.dot(self.x.T, delta)
        self.grad_b = np.sum(delta, axis=0)

        self.grad_x = np.dot(delta, self.w.T)

    def update(self, eta):  # update of weight and bias
        self.w -= eta * self.grad_w
        self.b -= eta * self.grad_b


# - Initialization of each network layer -
middle_layer = MiddleLayer(n_in, n_mid)
output_layer = OutputLayer(n_mid, n_out)

# -- learn --
for i in range(epoch):

    # Randomly scramble the index value
    index_random = np.arange(n_data)
    np.random.shuffle(index_random)

    # Used for the display of results
    total_error = 0
    plot_x = []
    plot_y = []

    for idx in index_random:

        x = input_data[idx:idx + 1]  # input
        t = correct_data[idx:idx + 1]  # correct answer

        # Forward spread
        middle_layer.forward(x.reshape(1, 1))  # Convert the input to a matrix
        output_layer.forward(middle_layer.y)

        # Backpropagation
        output_layer.backward(t.reshape(1, 1))  # Convert the correct answer to a matrix
        middle_layer.backward(output_layer.grad_x)

        # Update of weights and biases
        middle_layer.update(eta)
        output_layer.update(eta)

        if i % interval == 0:
            y = output_layer.y.reshape(-1)  # Restore the matrix to a vector

            # Error calculation
            total_error += 1.0 / 2.0 * np.sum(np.square(y - t))  # Square sum error

            # Output record
            plot_x.append(x)
            plot_y.append(y)

    if i % interval == 0:
        # Display the number of epochs and errors
        print("Epoch:" + str(i) + "/" + str(epoch), "Error:" + str(total_error / n_data))

        # Display the output with a graph
        plt.plot(input_data, correct_data, linestyle="dashed")
        plt.scatter(plot_x, plot_y, marker="+")
        plt.show()
```

Comment: bias: `self.b=wb_with*np.random.randn(n)`  . b gradient: `MiddleLayer`:delta=grad_y*(1-self.y)*self.y   self.grad_b=np.sum(delta,axis=0) .  `OutputLayer`: delta=self.y-t   self.grand_b=np.sum(delta,axis=0。

Comment: I came in accordance with the document, which is grand_b=np.sum(delta,axis=0).

Comment: Ok, it is a vertical sum on a row vector, essentially transforming the row vector into a simple array, like the flatten or ravel operations. It might have been introduced because `b` is also only a simple array and not a row vector. It would perhaps be better to have all as row vectors or all the vectors as simple arrays.

Comment: I got it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If increasing the number of epochs worked, the model needed more training.

But you may be overfitting... Notice that the cosine function is a periodic function, yet you are using only monotonic functions (sigmoid, and identity) to approximate it.

So while on the bounded interval of your data it may work:

[image]

It does not generalize well:

[image]

---

Code for the above plots:

```py
import math as m
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.datasets as datasets

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

t, _ = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=7500, centers=[[0, 0]], cluster_std=1, random_state=0)
X = np.array(list(filter(lambda x : m.cos(4*x[0]) - x[1] < -.5 or m.cos(4*x[0]) - x[1] > .5, t)))
Y = np.array([1 if m.cos(4*x[0]) - x[1] >= 0 else LABEL for x in X])

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(8, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy")

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=500, epochs=3000)

# create a mesh to plot in
h = .02  # step size in the mesh
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
meshData = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Z = model.predict(meshData)
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=.3, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
ax.axis('off')

# Plot also the training points
T = model.predict(X)
T = T.reshape(X[:,0].shape)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], color=colors[T].tolist(), s=10, alpha=0.9)
plt.show()

# add duplicate plotting code here to generate second plot
# predicting on data generated from a blob
# with a larger standard deviation
```

Comment: Which incentive function should I choose?

Comment: This is not something that will be solved by a different incentive function - what you have now for a regression problem is good. Using period activation functions is an option but it's an open research area - you could try looking into that.

Comment: I will learn the periodic activation function. But for the same code, why can the code learn the sin function normally?

Comment: What do you mean by normally?

Comment: The original code is `correct_data = np.sin(input_data)`. Is learning the sin function also overfitting? The error is as follows:
Epoch:0/2001 Error:0.28636468640868795
Epoch: 200/2001 Error: 0.008677233849354597
Epoch: 400/2001 Error: 0.0055141893668735524
Epoch: 600/2001 Error: 0.0026439447925640886
Epoch: 800/2001 Error: 0.0007932947895374446
Epoch: 1000/2001 Error: 0.0002676688590091671
Epoch: 1200/2001 Error: 9.509371114398377e-05
Epoch: 1400/2001 Error: 4.0628968777858185e-05
Epoch: 1600/2001 Error: 1.928746125721775e-05
Epoch: 1800/2001 Error: 1.2606182736090473e-05

Comment: Yes because sin is also periodic - your model will likely not generalize well especially past the boundaries of your training data

Comment: I understand that the sin function and the sigmoid function are a bit similar in shape, so it may be overfitting, but the shape of the cos function is a bit different, so more training is needed.

Comment: @jaried : If I run the original code multiple times, essentially changing the start point of the random number generator, in the 3rd or 4th run the network converges to the cosine function (even with only 2 middle nodes). So it seems to be a question of the initialization of the weights, not of the length of the learning cycle.

Comment: @LutzLehmann In each run, the weights and deviations are initialized only once. Class instantiation: # - Initialization of each network layer -
`middle_layer = MiddleLayer(n_in, n_mid)`
`output_layer = OutputLayer(n_mid, n_out)`

Comment: @jaried : Yes. I run it the code in a jupyter notebook, so that the RNG gets only initialized once, and not the same way in every run.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I found that it may be a cache problem of PyCharm, I updated the problem.

Comment: @jaried : I think that the number of learning steps is a function of the initial weight configuration. There are some where you need 20000 epochs, and some where 400 epochs give already a good result. So with only a small number of trial runs one can get wide discrepancies.

Comment: @LutzLehmann  You are right, it is indeed a matter of weight and biases. I used np.random.seed(2021) and I have been unable to learn the cos function, but using np.random.seed(10), the error is very small at the 600th epoch.

Comment: @Galletti_Lance  How did you make your picture? Can you share it?

Comment: @jaried added the code