# Why can't the neural network use the cos activation function to learn the cos function?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

When I used the Sigmoid activation function to learn the cos function, the error has not been reduced. Someone suggested that I use the periodic activation function. But I use the cos activation function to learn the cos function. If I use a random seed number of 10, the error starts to decrease, but then rises to about 0.26. What is the problem with my code?

Related questions:

[Neural network back propagation regression, how to correctly learn the cos function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462366)

Related parameters:

Random seed number: 10

middle layer:

Forward propagation: cos activation function

Back propagation: Differentiation of the cos activation function: sin activation function

Output layer：

Forward propagation: identity activation function

Back propagation: Differentiation of the identity activation function

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# -- Prepare input and correct answer data --
input_data = np.arange(0, np.pi * 2, 0.1)  # input
correct_data = np.cos(input_data)  # correct answer
input_data = (input_data - np.pi) / np.pi  # Converge the input to within the range of -1.0-1.0
n_data = len(correct_data)  # The amount of data

# -- Each set value --
n_in = 1  # Number of neurons in the input layer
n_mid = 3  # Number of neurons in the middle layer
n_out = 1  # Number of neurons in the output layer

wb_width = 0.01  # The spread of weights and biases
eta = 0.1  # Learning coefficient
epoch = 200001
interval = 200  # Interval practice for displaying progress

np.random.seed(10)


# -- middle layer --
class MiddleLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_upper, n):  # Initial setup
        self.w = wb_width * np.random.randn(n_upper, n)  # Weight (matrix)
        self.b = wb_width * np.random.randn(n)  # bias (vector)

    def forward(self, x):  # Forward propagation
        self.x = x
        u = np.dot(x, self.w) + self.b
        # self.y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-u))  # Sigmoid function
        self.y = np.cos(u)  # cos function

    def backward(self, grad_y):  # Backward propagation
        # delta = grad_y * (1 - self.y) * self.y  # Differentiation of sigmoid function
        delta = grad_y * np.sin(self.y)  # Differentiation of the cos function

        self.grad_w = np.dot(self.x.T, delta)
        self.grad_b = np.sum(delta, axis=0)

        self.grad_x = np.dot(delta, self.w.T)

    def update(self, eta):  # Update of weights and biases
        self.w -= eta * self.grad_w
        self.b -= eta * self.grad_b


# -- Output layer --
class OutputLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_upper, n):  # Initial setup
        self.w = wb_width * np.random.randn(n_upper, n)  # Weight (matrix)
        self.b = wb_width * np.random.randn(n)  #  bias (vector)

    def forward(self, x):  # Forward propagation
        self.x = x
        u = np.dot(x, self.w) + self.b
        self.y = u  # Identity function

    def backward(self, t):  # Backward propagation
        delta = self.y - t

        self.grad_w = np.dot(self.x.T, delta)
        self.grad_b = np.sum(delta, axis=0)

        self.grad_x = np.dot(delta, self.w.T)

    def update(self, eta):  # Update of weights and biases
        self.w -= eta * self.grad_w
        self.b -= eta * self.grad_b


# -- Initialization of each network layer --
middle_layer = MiddleLayer(n_in, n_mid)
output_layer = OutputLayer(n_mid, n_out)

# -- learning --
for i in range(epoch):

    
    index_random = np.arange(n_data)
    np.random.shuffle(index_random)

    # For display of results
    total_error = 0
    plot_x = []
    plot_y = []

    for idx in index_random:

        x = input_data[idx:idx + 1]  # input
        t = correct_data[idx:idx + 1]  # correct answer

        # Forward spread
        middle_layer.forward(x.reshape(1, 1))  # Convert input to matrix
        output_layer.forward(middle_layer.y)

        # Backpropagation
        output_layer.backward(t.reshape(1, 1))  # Convert the correct answer to a matrix
        middle_layer.backward(output_layer.grad_x)

        # Update of weights and biases
        middle_layer.update(eta)
        output_layer.update(eta)

        if i % interval == 0:
            y = output_layer.y.reshape(-1)  # Restore matrix to vector

            # Error calculation
            total_error += 1.0 / 2.0 * np.sum(np.square(y - t))  # Sum of Square Error

            # Output record
            plot_x.append(x)
            plot_y.append(y)

    if i % interval == 0:
        # Graphical display of output
        # plt.plot(input_data, correct_data, linestyle="dashed")
        # plt.scatter(plot_x, plot_y, marker="+")
        # plt.show()

        # Show epoch times and error
        print("Epoch:" + str(i) + "/" + str(epoch), "Error:" + str(total_error / n_data))
```

Output：

```
Epoch:0/200001 Error:0.3272790193874323
Epoch:200/200001 Error:0.08499547807075207
Epoch:400/200001 Error:0.04471511893846511
...
Epoch:7800/200001 Error:0.05923524015075548
Epoch:8000/200001 Error:0.27576556813010333
Epoch:8200/200001 Error:0.05534852281515205
Epoch:8400/200001 Error:0.261993559034807
Epoch:8600/200001 Error:0.26593529184409787
...
Epoch:11200/200001 Error:0.2747849125301656
...
```

[image: Error distribution]